# Nuget push to vso not listed

Tags: powershell, nuget, azure-artifacts

I'm trying to push some historical packages to a nuget feed on visualstudio.com (vsts, vso) using Powershell.

The command is:

```
PS D:\> nuget.exe push -Source "VDS AppCore on VSO" -ApiKey VSTS d:\ActApps\Prescient\Source-Workflow\Prescient.RView\pa
ckages\VDS.AppCore.Core.1.5.3.142\VDS.AppCore.core.1.5.3.142.nupkg
```

The system claims this is working. This is the feedback I get:

```
Pushing VDS.AppCore.Core.1.5.3.142.nupkg to 'https://xxx.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/0265d3e2-35f2-4a0e-b240-d
a573c6409d6/nuget/v2/'...
  PUT https://xxx.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/0265d3e2-35f2-4a0e-b240-da573c6409d6/nuget/v2/
CredentialProvider.VSS: Getting new credentials for source:https://xxx.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/AppCore/nug
et/v3/index.json, scope:vso.packaging_write vso.drop_write
  Accepted https://xxx.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/0265d3e2-35f2-4a0e-b240-da573c6409d6/nuget/v2/ 5510ms
Your package was pushed.
```

The first time I ran this there was a popup for login which succeeded. All subsequent calls claim the package was pushed.

I've pushed about 12 packages so far but none of them show in the list of packages on the vsts website.

Why are the packages pushed from the command not showing in the list of packages for the feed provided?

Comment: I can use the command to push packages to VSTS feed. Did you use a private agent to build? And what's the `nuget.config` file you used? what if you update the source `VDS AppCore on VSO` with credential (`nuget sources update -Name "new" -Source <feed URL> -UserName <alternate username> -Password <alternate password>`) and try again?

Comment: What do you mean about historical packages? Is the version of these packages older than the packages already exists in VSTS feed?

Comment: @Marina-MSFT I'll need to try that tomorrow. I'm guessing the <alternate> items are new ones I make up, correct?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT The version of the packages I am trying to push IS older than the ones already in the feed. Is that an issue?

Comment: @WillTartak Alternate credential used in `nuget sources update` will add the source's credential in `nuget.config`. And it will save you to input username and password manually.

Comment: @WillTartak And can you find the packages upload in VSTS feed now? If 
 there already has higher versions than VDS.AppCore.Core `1.5.3.142` in VSTS, you should check the version `1.5.3.142`as the way Eddie said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is expected behavior if the pushed package version is older than the one already exist in the feed since VSTS only list the latest version of the package. If you want to check the historical versions, click on the package to open the package overview page and then click on the version, it will list the older packages.
[image]

Comment: What do you do if you want to upload an older version in case a project wants to access that version instead of the latest? @Eddie - MSFT

Comment: @WillTartak Just upload it to the feed like the steps you have taken. As soon as the old version is uploaded to the feed successfully, it can be accessed by the project. You don't need to take any other action. Just make sure that the version is specified when you install the nuget package to the project. For example: Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 8.0.2

Comment: you are right, the files are there. I had expected history to show on one of the panels on the right side of the page, not as a dropdown next to the name. When I click on the dropdown the other versions I've uploaded are there. Thanks for your help.